# Merge two spreadsheets using python - Source of columns in new sheets alternates between source files

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I would like to write a python code to merge two spreadsheets in .csv format so that the first column in the new sheet is from either of the source sheets and all other new columns are derived in alternating order from the source sheets.

Here is an example (shown in spreadsheet format):

Source 1:

```
    (A) name 1  (A) name 2  (A) name 3  (A) name 4
class 1             
class 2             
class 3             
class 4
```

Source 2:

```
    (B) name 1  (B) name 2  (B) name 3  (B) name 4
class 1             
class 2             
class 3             
class 4
```

Desired outcome:

```
    (A) name 1  (B) name 1  (A) name 2  (B) name 2  (A) name 3  (B) name 3  (A) name 4  (B) name 4
class 1                             
class 2                             
class 3                             
class 4
```

EDIT:

As requested, here is an example from my data (shown in .csv format)

Sheet 1:

```
,(F) Abies amabilis,(F) Abies balsamea,(F) Abies bifolia,(F) Abies concolor,(F) Abies fraseri,(F) Abies grandis,(F) Abies lasiocarpa,(F) Abies magnifica,(F) Abies procera,(F) Larix decidua,(F) Larix laricina,(F) Picea abies,(F) Picea engelmannii,(F) Picea glauca,(F) Picea mariana,(F) Picea pungens,(F) Picea sitchensis,(F) Pinus albicaulis,(F) Pinus aristata,(F) Pinus attenuata,(F) Pinus banksiana,(F) Pinus cembroides,(F) Pinus clausa,(F) Pinus contorta,(F) Pinus coulteri,(F) Pinus echinata,(F) Pinus edulis,(F) Pinus elliottii,(F) Pinus engelmannii,(F) Pinus flexilis,(F) Pinus halepensis,(F) Pinus jeffreyi,(F) Pinus lambertiana,(F) Pinus leiophylla,(F) Pinus longaeva,(F) Pinus monophylla,(F) Pinus monticola,(F) Pinus mugo,(F) Pinus muricata,(F) Pinus palustris,(F) Pinus ponderosa,(F) Pinus pumila,(F) Pinus pungens,(F) Pinus quadrifolia,(F) Pinus radiata,(F) Pinus resinosa,(F) Pinus rigida,(F) Pinus serotina,(F) Pinus strobiformis,(F) Pinus strobus,(F) Pinus sylvestris,(F) Pinus taeda,(F) Pinus thunbergii,(F) Pinus torreyana,(F) Pinus virginiana,(F) Pseudotsuga macrocarpa,(F) Pseudotsuga menziesii,(F) Tsuga canadensis,(F) Tsuga heterophylla,(F) Tsuga mertensiana
48,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
52,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
58,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
```

Sheet 2:

```
,(M) Abies amabilis,(M) Abies balsamea,(M) Abies bifolia,(M) Abies concolor,(M) Abies fraseri,(M) Abies grandis,(M) Abies lasiocarpa,(M) Abies magnifica,(M) Abies procera,(M) Larix decidua,(M) Larix laricina,(M) Picea engelmannii,(M) Picea glauca,(M) Picea mariana,(M) Picea pungens,(M) Picea sitchensis,(M) Pinus albicaulis,(M) Pinus aristata,(M) Pinus attenuata,(M) Pinus banksiana,(M) Pinus cembroides,(M) Pinus clausa,(M) Pinus contorta,(M) Pinus coulteri,(M) Pinus echinata,(M) Pinus edulis,(M) Pinus elliottii,(M) Pinus engelmannii,(M) Pinus flexilis,(M) Pinus halepensis,(M) Pinus jeffreyi,(M) Pinus lambertiana,(M) Pinus leiophylla,(M) Pinus longaeva,(M) Pinus monophylla,(M) Pinus monticola,(M) Pinus muricata,(M) Pinus palustris,(M) Pinus ponderosa,(M) Pinus pumila,(M) Pinus pungens,(M) Pinus quadrifolia,(M) Pinus radiata,(M) Pinus resinosa,(M) Pinus rigida,(M) Pinus serotina,(M) Pinus strobiformis,(M) Pinus strobus,(M) Pinus sylvestris,(M) Pinus thunbergii,(M) Pinus torreyana,(M) Pinus virginiana,(M) Tsuga canadensis,(M) Tsuga heterophylla,(M) Tsuga mertensiana
48,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
52,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
58,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I am a very novice coder, so what I have tried is hardly worth mentioning. However, I initially assumed that maybe I could link the sheets using zip, which works for lists. I also thought that maybe I could do something like

```
for line in "Source 1.csv" and row in "Source 2.csv:
        #then split the lines into lists and write to an outfile using list indices
```

In advance, I am very appreciative of your help!

Comment: Your example is a little confusing. Are the first lines the columns? It might be better to supply at least a couple lines of raw data from a file in your question (since .csv files are plain text).

Comment: Ah, just the info needed. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track using `zip()`, but it gets a little tricky because it returns a list of pairs of values from each source file. The following deals with that by flattening the nested sequences. So I think something along the lines of the following should work. You can also use `zip()` (or `itertools.izip()`) to iterate through the rows of the two csv files in parallel.

Note I generally try to use the `csv` module when dealing with files in that format, as it can often save a lot of time and trouble, plus it's fairly easy to use.

```
import csv
import itertools

with open("Source 1.csv", "rb") as source1, \
     open("Source 2.csv", "rb") as source2, \
     open("merged_output.csv", "wb") as merged_output:

    source1_reader = csv.reader(source1, delimiter=',')
    source2_reader = csv.reader(source2, delimiter=',')
    merged_output_writer = csv.writer(merged_output, delimiter=',')

    for row1, row2 in itertools.izip(source1_reader, source2_reader):
        merged_output_writer.writerow(
            tuple(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.izip(row1, row2))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly the kickstarter I needed to solve this and get it moving towards downstream applications. Perfect!

Comment: You're welcome. Hope my use of `itertools` doesn't make this too difficult to understand. There are a number simpler but less-optimal ways of doing essentially the same same thing...which might have been better for someone like yourself whose just learning. On the other hand, if you can wrap your brain around this, you should be well on your way to becoming what they would call a formidable [Pythonista](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html). Have fun!